# GCC 7.3 and 8.2 (ubuntu18.04) problem with sqrt() call

Tags: gcc

Here's a simple C code:

```c
#include <math.h>

float f( float x ) { return sqrtf( x ); }
```

GCC 7.3 and 8.2 (amd64, ubuntu 18.04) generates very strange code:

```
f:
  pxor xmm2,xmm2
  sqrtss xmm1,xmm0
  ucomiss xmm2,xmm0
  ja .L8    ; 0 < x? then, jump to .L8.
  movaps xmm0,xmm1
  ret
.L8:
  sub rsp,24
  movss [rsp+12],xmm1  ; save sqrtss result.
  call sqrtf
  movss xmm1,[rsp+12]  ; restore sqrtss result.
  add rsp,24
  movaps xmm0,xmm1
  ret
```

This behavior I see on GCC 7.3 and 8.2 from ubuntu-18.04 repos AND on MinGW-w64 as well. I couldn't find this bug on GCC Bugzilla (and I cannot report it).

Any thoughts?

Comment: PS: Similar behaviour with GCC cross compiler for AArch64 and ARM (AArch32).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You neither provide the complete code, nor explain in which way the assembler code is "strange" and why you think it's a bug. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how to improve your question, then edit it to provide enough information to get a good picture of the issue.

Comment: The complete code is there... just compile it with: gcc -O2 -S test.c

Answer (score 1):

*GCC* is generating strictly compliant floating point math calculations with the code you compiled (I suspect with **-O2** or **-O3**). I guess you were expecting it to compile it down to something like the following (in *gas* format assembler):

```
f:
.LFB9:
        .cfi_startproc
        sqrtss  %xmm0, %xmm0
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE9:
```

You need to disable the strict math conformance rules by using `-ffast-math` to generate the faster "optimized" code. Note that this option enables the

```
-fno-math-errno
-funsafe-math-optimizations
-ffinite-math-only
-fno-rounding-math
-fno-signaling-nans
-fcx-limited-range
-fexcess-precision=fast
```

*GCC* options, so beware of loss of precision and loss of math errors.

Comment: -ffast-math has no effect on the generated code I presented.